# Orchard: Placing content type

Tags: orchardcms

Using Orchard 1.5, TheThemeMachine
I created a ContentType (called TestTeaser) in Dashboard, which renders nicely in the "Content"-section.
But I want it to appear in another one, specified in the theme (themeMachine), like "BeforeContent".

I added this to the placement.info of ThemeMachine:

```
<Match Path="~/testteaser">
     <Place Parts_Title="BeforeContent:1"/>
</Match>
```

I can see, that it matches, because now the Title is not showing in "Content" (as the rest of the Teaser-Type), but also nowhere else.

I thought in 1.5 this should be possible. (read a posting somewhere by bLeroy)

How would I do this???

thnx
Reinhard

Comment: The posting about 1.5 being able to do this is: http://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/358527/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Afaik, in order to push a part to a global zone, you need to add "/" prefix to zone name (so the zone name should be `/BeforeContent`). This is to distinguish global zones from the local ones.

Comment: My God!! Where did you find these valueable piece of information??But this makes perfect sense, to distinguish zones :_) It works!! Thanks a lot !!

Comment: This is really something I would NEVER EVER find by myself (which means it would take a week of frustration). It took some minutes and a google search for "orchard placement beforecontent" and Piotr answer + Stack Overflow to have my title which disappeared with "BeforeContent" alone start working as expected! THANKS A MILLION!